# Magento multi store SSL share

Tags: magento, ssl, ssl-certificate

I use magento multi store function. Every store has it's own url (store.com, store1.com, store2.com)

store.com has ssl certificate.

Will store1.com and store2.com be able to use the secure store.com for all the activities that require SSL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SSLs will need to be unique to an IP address, but you can buy multi-domain SSLs for domains that share an IP